# cakePHP query using find() method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, find, cakephp-1.2

how can I convert this query to use cakePHP's method `find()` ?

query:

```
SELECT Ch.id, COUNT( DU.d_id ) AS a, SUM(DU.d_id) AS b
FROM c AS Ch
LEFT JOIN du AS DU ON DU.c_id = Ch.id AND MONTH( DU.created ) = MONTH( NOW( ) )
LEFT JOIN d AS D ON DU.d_id = D.id
GROUP BY Ch.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Ch->find(
    'all',      
    'fields' => array(
               'Ch.id','COUNT( DU.d_id ) AS a', 'SUM(DU.d_id) AS b'),
    'joins'  => array(
                      array(
                            'table' => 'du',
                            'alias' => 'DU',
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array('DU.c_id = Ch.id AND MONTH( DU.created ) = MONTH( NOW( )')),
                       array(
                            'table' => 'd',
                            'alias' => 'D',
                            'type' => 'LEFT',
                            'conditions' => array('DU.c_id = Ch.id AND MONTH( DU.created ) = MONTH( NOW( )')),
    'group' => 'Ch.id');
```

I haven't tested. More info on Cake JOINs:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find